# Terminology: What does it mean when an email is "in the clear"?

Tags: security, https

A practice exam question is formulated as such:

"Person A sends an e-mail to person B via. a HTTPS connection. Can an attacker read the e-mail in the clear?"

I haven't encountered the phrasing "in the clear" in the book, and looking it up without context, it means "no longer in danger or under suspicion". Does it just mean "once the e-mail has arrived at person B's computer"?

Comment: This looks like a question for SuperUser and not StackOverflow. In the clear probably means it's readable.

Comment: In cryptographic terminology ['plaintext'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext), 'cleartext' and sometimes just 'clear' is material that is _not_ encrypted (while encrypted data is 'ciphertext'). Usually/traditionally we say 'in clear' without 'the', but that's only a small difference and easily mistaken or changed. You need to find this test-setter's assumptions or conditions because the information you quoted is not enough to determine a valid answer, especially since standard email never uses 'a' (single) HTTPS connection, but I recommend security.SX rather than superuser.

Comment: Noted, and thanks!